# How can i use a while loop on this program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to know how to use a while loop on the output so it keeps outputting "Line: ".
What i am trying to do is reverse each word in a string but it stops once i use one input, i need to use a while loop to keep getting an output and the while loop has to stop on an empty input.

My workaround:

```
a =input("Line: ")
b=a.split()
ans=''
while a != '':
  for word in b:
    word = word[::-1]
    ans=ans+word+' '
    a =input("Line: ")
    print(ans.rstrip())
```

The output i want:

```
Line: hello world
olleh dlrow
Line: extra
artxe
Line:
```

The output I'm getting:

```
Line: hello world
olleh
Line: extra
olleh dlrow
Line:
```

Comment: Did you try to write `while` above this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

Comment: I still don't know how to do it? I tried to do a while loop and stuff but i get an incorrect output :(

Comment: @jonrsharpe think the [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) tutorial's more appropriate here.

Comment: So where is your code with a while loop, and **what exactly is wrong with it?**

Comment: I edited my post with my attempt at doing a while loop. I just get the wrong output each time? So when i type in "hello world" it should output "elloh dlroW"

Comment: *"I just get wrong output"* - please edit the question with your input, the output you expect *and the output you're getting*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try in this way

```
a=input('input:')
while a.strip()!='': 

    b=a.split()
    ans=''
    while len(b) >0 :
       word=b[0][::-1]
       ans+=word+" "
       b.pop(0)
    print ans
    a=input('input:')

#output i ma hsejar !aloH
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a `while True` loop and `break`:

```
while True:
    line = input("Line: ")
    if not line:
        break
    ...
```

This works because empty strings `""` evaluate `False`-y. You can also make your code more efficient with lists:

```
words = []
while True:
    line = input("Line: ")
    if not line:
        break
    for word in line.split():
        words.append(word[::-1])
print(" ".join(words))
```

This avoids the constant string concatenation with `+`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I need to print out each time they input something reversed. Your program prints out all their inputs reversed when no input is detected. Can you please print out the input at each line for me?

Comment: You can alter the code for yourself: move the assignment of an empty list to `words` and the `print` call inside the `while` loop.